# Google chrome consumes 100% CPU for nearly a minute

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cpu-usage

I have disabled hardware acceleration in my `chrome://settings`. I have also visited `chrome://flags` and disabled every one of the flags listed in [this post](//superuser.com/a/697573/123710).

I restarted the system (and not just the browser), fired up chrome and here is the CPU usage graph shown in Windows Task Manager:

> [image]
>
> 1 square (X-axis) = 5 seconds

The system was not connected to the internet when opening chrome. I only had 2 tabs restored in the window from last browsing session. I have only three browser extensions enabled at the moment:

- HTTPS Everywhere 2015.8.13
- ScriptSafe 1.0.6.18
- ModHeader 2.0.5

What could be causing this much CPU usage, for such a large amount of time? As can be seen from the graph above, the CPU (including kernel times) stays at a constant 100% usage for at least 40 seconds.

After the usage drops down, it stays there for almost entire session, never going beyond 5%.

---

### EDIT

Chrome does not allow me to access *Chrome Task Manager* unless it has finished consuming CPU entirely. After the process is finished, I noticed only the 5 processes enlisted above (2 tabs and 3 plug-ins/extensions).

The page `chrome://plugins` lists the following active plugins:

- Widevine Content Decryption Module - Version: 1.4.8.823
- Chrome PDF Viewer (2 files)
- Native Client
- Adobe Flash Player - Version: 18.0.0.209

In Windows Task Manager's processes list, I see that chrome distributes the CPU usage evenly to all `chrome.exe` processes listed there. Thus, each of them has about 10-12% of CPU assigned to them.

---

### EDIT-2

System hardware:

- Asus M5A97 Board
- AMD FX-8320 Processor
- 2x4GB DDR3 1800 MHz RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 GPU
- Samsung 840 EVO 120 GB SSD

---

The event trace log file can be downloaded [from here](//drive.google.com/file/d/0B97Nit_O7j6ZMkRMOXFfUlBTS0U/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Post your PC's hardware please.

Comment: @Moab added the details above

Comment: In Chrome activate **chrome://flags/#trace-export-events-to-etw** and run https://github.com/google/UIforETW/ to capture a xperf trace of the CPU usage. Zip and share the trace.

Comment: @magicandre1981 There is no flag regarding `trace-export-events-to-etw`. I'm downloading the package and will share the trace once done, if it is not dependent on the flag

Comment: this flag seams to requires Chrome 46. I see it in my 46.0.2490.52.

Comment: only run this xperf command (the Win8.1 WPT  also works in Win7, but not the Win10 WPT!!!) before you start chrome: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD after chrome is open and the CPU usage is gone, press a key to stop it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've generated the trace file. It is around 400 MB in size (40 when compressed with LZMA) It'd still take some time for me to upload.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is the trace file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97Nit_O7j6ZMkRMOXFfUlBTS0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, the CPU usage comes from reading registry values. To also capture registry data, run this command: **xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+REGISTRY+PROFILE -stackwalk Profile+RegQueryKey+RegEnumerateKey+RegEnumerateValueKey+RegDeleteKey+RegCreateKey+RegOpenKey+RegSetValue+RegDeleteValue+RegQueryValue+RegQueryMultipleValue+RegSetInformation+RegFlush+RegKcbCreate+RegKcbDelete+RegVirtualize+RegCloseKey -BufferSize 2048 -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\HighCPUUsageWithRegistry.etl** and share the new file

Comment: @magicandre1981 All of a sudden, I rebooted the system 3-4 hours ago and now the CPU utilisation did not exceed 20%. The bootup was quick as well. I'll go through the trace file too and see what I can infer.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is often caused by Chrome Software tool

It is present in

> %localappdata%\google\chrome\User Data\SwReporter\81.234.200\software_reporter_tool.exe

> The version number 81.234.200 after the SwReporter folder can be different for different versions of Chrome

[image]

**But if you delete that file the solution is temporary because it will
automatically updated when a new version of Chrome is installed
so the best solution is to permanently disable it**

How to Disable Permanently:

1.Open Regedit

> 2.Go to the following key
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies

> 3.Under Policies, go to Google\Chrome.If folder not there you need to make it

> 4.Create the following DWORD (32-bit) value:ChromeCleanupEnabled Enter 0 for disabling the tool

> 5.Create another DWORD (32-bit) value with the following name:
> ChromeCleanupReportingEnabled Enter 0 for disabing the software updater

Or you can paste this content to new registry .reg file and run it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"ChromeCleanupEnabled"=dword:00000000
"ChromeCleanupReportingEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

**Also always**

Use chrome latest version and refrain opening too much tabs or use Great suspender extension to suspend tabs

Dont install too much extensions if you have done remove or disable it

Source:https://www.itechtics.com/disable-software-reporter-tool/

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you tried Chrome Task Manager <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>? It will show you the tabs and extension that are active and taking that much of CPU usage.
2. Determine if you have any plugins installed.
3. Clear the Chrome browser cache.
4. Try "The Great Suspender" from Chrome web store.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned "_Chrome does not allow me to access Chrome Task Manager unless it has finished consuming CPU entirely_." Edited the question above as well.

Comment: have you tried other method ??

Comment: I've listed the enabled plugins in the question above. I have tried restarting the browser after clearing caches. There was no effect whatsoever. In the Windows Task Manager, I see that chrome distributes CPU evenly to all the `chrome.exe` processes listed. I still have yet to try the great suspender app/extension though.